# Is this minus in the proof by substitution a typo?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-explanation, arithmetic, substitution

I am reading a proof about showing that if $a \equiv a' \pmod m$ and $b\equiv b' \pmod m$ then $a + b \equiv a' + b'\pmod m$ and $ab \equiv a'b'\pmod m$.
The proof uses substitution to show that (for the case of addition) the difference $(a + b) - (a' + b')$ is divisible by $m$. By substitution the proof shows that the above expression is $m(j -k)$ which is a multiple of $m$. With the same approach it shows that for the case of multiplication $ab - a'b'$ is equivalent to $m(ka + kb -jkm)$.
The proof has defined: $a = mj + a'$ and $b=mk + b'$
Now the question I have is if that $-$ (minus) in the expression after the substitution is a typo or it serves some specific convention. Because in the case of the addition we have:
$(a + b) - (a' + b') \Leftrightarrow (mj + a' + mk + b') - a' - b' \Leftrightarrow mj + mk \Leftrightarrow m(j + k)$

So I don't understand why the proof says: $m(j -k)$. I understand that we could just define $k = -z$ and consider they are the same expression but I don't understand why we need to do that. Same for the multiplication.
Is this a typo or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Did they mention what are $k$ and $j$? Given congrunces, it depends on how you relate $a,a'$ and $b,b'$

Comment: I updated the post. The proof has defined: $a = mj + a'$ and $b=mk + b'$ same as I have

Comment: You have expanded $-(a'-b')$ as $-a'-b'$. Oops!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That was a typo, Corrected it

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: Does the update help?

Comment: The mysterious minus sign is just a typo in the book. It should be +.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I thought so, but wanted to make sure I am not missing something

Answer (score -1):

If a is congruent to a' (mod m) then a= a'+ km for some integer k.  If b is congruent to b' (mod m) then b= b'+ jm for some integer j.  ab= (a'+ km)(b'+ jm)= a'b'+ kmb'+ a'jm+ kjm^2= a'b'+ (kb'+ a'j+ kjm)m.
That is, ab is equal to a'b' plus some integer multiple of m so ab is congrjent to a'b' (mod m).

Comment: Your answer is not readable, please use MathJax.

Comment: This is not related to what I am asking in the post though